# Check DependencyProperty is registered

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I know if "Status" DependencyProperty is registered, before I run the code below again?

Code:

```
public readonly DependencyProperty StatusProperty ;

    public string Status
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(StatusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StatusProperty, value); }
    }

StatusProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Status", typeof(string), typeof(CWindow), new PropertyMetadata());
```

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/cdd0dcdf-9187-4cd9-80de-4d3f51a4f970

Answer (score 0):

You will need reflection to find out the Depenedency Properties that are already registered.

```
using System.Reflection;

foreach (FieldInfo fInfo in CWindow.GetType().GetFields())
{
    if (fInfo.FieldType.Name == "DependencyProperty")
    {
        if (fInfo.GetValue(null) == "Status")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Status Property already Registered");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get Non-static field requires a target. error at if (fInfo.GetValue(null) == "Status")

Comment: have you created an instance for cwindow?is that a control.If so replace cWindow in the foreach with the instance name.since i didnt know your instance name i used the type name cWindow.use <cwindowinstanceName>.GetType().GetFields()

Comment: O am changing CWindow to "this". I thought is the current window.

Comment: No i still don't get what you mean sorry.

Comment: did you include the reflection code and did that work for you mate